# Download file to specific directory

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to download a file to specific directory but I got the file downloaded in the same path of the python code

```
import requests
from pathlib import Path

def downloadFile(link, destfolder):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36'}
    r = requests.get(link,headers=headers, stream=True)
    filename=link.split('/')[-1]
    downloaded_file = open(filename, 'wb')

    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=256):
        if chunk:
            downloaded_file.write(chunk)
            
link='http://index-of.es/Python/A.Byte.of.Python.1.92.Swaroop.C.H.2009.pdf'
Path('Files').mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True) 
downloadFile(link, 'Files')
```

How can I change the folder that I will download the file into it to be `Files` folder ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply prepend the folder path to the filename. You can use `os.path.join`(for platform independent/robust solution) or simple string manipulation

```
import requests
from pathlib import Path
import os

def downloadFile(link, destfolder):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36'}
    r = requests.get(link,headers=headers, stream=True)
    filename=link.split('/')[-1]
    downloaded_file = open(os.path.join(destfolder, filename), 'wb')

    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=256):
        if chunk:
            downloaded_file.write(chunk)
            
link='http://index-of.es/Python/A.Byte.of.Python.1.92.Swaroop.C.H.2009.pdf'
Path('Files').mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True) 
downloadFile(link, 'Files')
```

Comment: I just waited for the time-limited to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you are giving the filename try to add the path name like

```
filename="C:\myfolders\"+filename
```

this should work kindly let me know if there any issues. Thanks!